# How to add Hints to views?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

I want when the user accesses the activity or a new screen that has, for an example, a `ViewPager` or `ImageView` or any other view, a `hint` or `Tips` "informative text" appears tells the user what can be done with this view.

For an example, if it is a clickable `ImageView` a text appears tells the user if he long clicked that view an action will occur, Or if he swiped up a menu will appear.

just an informative text about the functionality assigned to the view

is something like that achievable?how?

Comment: Where do you want the hint? i.e. A Toast would suffice or you can implement a custom animation for that.

Comment: Please explain **completely and precisely** what this "hint" is supposed to look and work like. Then, and only then, can somebody tell you if this "hint" is "achievable".

Comment: You can use a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 1):

## METHOD 1

I made an android library to do that. You can use it directly from [here](https://github.com/hendrawd/HintedImageButton).

[image: demo1]
[image: demo2]

To use it, you just need to provide **contentDescription**, as easy as this:

```xml
<hendrawd.library.customview.HintedImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_xxx"
    android:contentDescription="Put your hint here!"
    android:background="@drawable/optional_selector"
    />
```

If you don't want to use `ImageButton` background, you can change the background directly or make it as `@null` to remove the background.

It will not only show hint when **long-clicked** but also **on mouse cursor hover** if you plug external mouse to your Android device.

---

## METHOD 2

Starting from **Android Oreo**, if your requirement is just to show simple tooltip to any `View`, you can use `android:tooltipText` attribute directly without the above library in order to display a simple Toast-like tooltip when user **long-presses** or **mouse hover** on a `View`

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/yourView"
    android:tooltipText="@string/view_tooltip"/>
```

Although it has a limitation with minimum API 26, you can still use it through the Support Library's `TooltipCompat` helper class

```kotlin
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(yourView, getString(R.string.view_tooltip))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this

1. A Toast would be the easiest.
2. An alert dialog.
3. You can create a custom animation for rich UI experience.

Answer (score 0):

For image-view you can use HintedImageButton. Java Code is here: [link](https://gist.github.com/scruffyfox/3894926)